# How to compare gaussian curvature and space-time curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I'm reading a book where I encountered [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature), which felt very nature, and it was well defined. 
However, in 4 space, people use Riemann curvature tensor, etc.

There's one big distinction was that Gaussian curvature was designed for parametrized surface, where the usual parameter, "time", were all embedded into the Riemann. Thus, even restricted to 2 spacial surface, they seemed to be somewhat very different.

How to compare between Gaussian curvature and Riemann curvature tensor? Was the former a special case of space time curvature?(i.e. the time was somehow "flat".)

Comment: The Wikipedia article about [sectional curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature) might help. For some caveats regarding the definition of Gaussian curvature, see this Math Overflow post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/345590

Comment: Related: [What is the qualitative difference in the information contained by Gaussian curvature and Riemann curvature tensor in General Relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293503/what-is-the-qualitative-difference-in-the-information-contained-by-gaussian-curv)

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/curvature-of-space-in-the-context-of-cosmology.988815/

Comment: You can also check sec. 5.9 of N.M.J. Woodhouse's General Relativity, which deals with exactly the same question you've asked.